# I am not able to overide updateItem method of cellFactory in javaFX

Tags: listview, javafx

IntelliJ is not letting me override `updateItem()` method ,it shows an error here ,saying remove refrence , does anyone knows whats wrong ?? Please help

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    public javafx.scene.control.ListView ListView;
    ObservableList list;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
      list = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Apple","Banana","pear");
      ListView.setItems(list);
      ListView.setCellFactory(param -> {
                ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>();

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String string, boolean empty);
}
```

Comment: wrong syntax .. read up in how to implement anonymous subclasses. hint: no semicolon after `new ListCell`, but opening bracket ..

Comment: I am still not getting it , i got this code from internet and still it is unable to overide the method

Comment: You have to subclass the class in order to override a method of said class. You can do this "inline" (i.e. create an anonymous class)—see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: I am new in java can you help  me with  the syntax

Comment: I linked to the official tutorial. Here's another tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/java-anonymous-classes

Comment: _i got this code from internet_ - no, you didn't. Details matter :)

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax for a custom `CellFactory` would look like this:

```
bookListView.setCellFactory(cell -> new ListCell<YOUR_OBJECT_TYPE>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(YOUR_OBJECT_TYPE item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        // Your update code goes here.

    }
});
```

You can learn more about how and why this works here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: @kleopatra But to answer your question, I learned a TON myself from answers just like this. Not every question requires a 5-page essay to learn and understand a coding concept.

Comment: no, but every _question_ requires to at least _look_ into a textbook/tutorial and at least c&p the code presented there. Which is what _you_ did for the OP, her not learning much today .. well, I know we tend to disagree on this matter ;)